# Bullnose tile, start and stop tiling job

Tags: shower, tiling

Getting ready to tile my first shower. Planning to start at the bottom and work up. Do I place the bullnose trim alongside the courses of tile as I go up? Or finish the big pieces then place all the bullnose pieces around the edge last?

While on the subject, is it ok to finish a few courses then come back the next day to finish, or should it all be done at once to avoid the thinset from drying out between courses? Is there anything I should do to clean the edge where stopped tiling for the day to ensure a good continuity when I restart?
Thanks for the input

Comment: Duplicate : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/162501/97780

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to install bullnose tile](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/162501/when-to-install-bullnose-tile)

Comment: Exact duplicate of the question noted in both comments posted by this user 30 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the bullnose either way, but if you finish the tile and come back to the bullnose be sure to gauge with a dry piece of bullnose and make any adjustments while the tile is still wet.

As far as installing the tile in sections, sometimes it is best to break it up, so the tile is not weighing down on the bottom courses, potentially moving them out of place. Just be sure to scrape any excess thinset off of the wall and sponge it off of the tile.